# JS serving and REST API from machine with changing IP address

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask, npm, axios

I have an app using React that interfaces to a REST server via axios. The REST server (flask) is on the same machine that is serving the build of the JS project. The project being served is the output of `npm run build`. npm serve is then used to deploy this package. The web interface is then viewed from a remote machine of a different IP.

The issue I have encountered is that the IP of the machine that is serving the site and the REST API may change. How to I go about changing the IP that axios is calling dynamically? At the moment I have a script that searches for the IP string in the js build and replaces it with the machines current IP.

Using utilities like `ip` have only been returning localhost. I guess I need to find a way to get the IP of who is serving the script?

Comment: Why are you trying to solve it in JS instead of just using a DNS?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `env` variables to solve these issues. One popular way is to use [cross-env](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env). Your `package.json` file would have a `build` command in the `script` section. You'll have to modify these to add the required configs as `environment variables` and use it in the code where required.

Example:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build:prod": "cross-env API_URL=http://myserverip.com NODE_ENV=production webpack --config     build/webpack.config.js",
    "build:dev": "cross-env API_URL=http://localhost:8000 NODE_ENV=development webpack --config     build/webpack.config.js"
  }
}
```

Then you can use different commands to build them. To build prod run `npm run build:prod`. To build dev run `npm run build:dev`.

In your code, you can use `process.env.API_URL`(in place where you write ip address/hostname) which will have different values based on the build. To allow webpack to replace these `env` variables, use webpack `Define` plugin as

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
    API_URL: JSON.stringify(process.env.API_URL),
  }
})
```

Comment: very cool. I will give this a shot and report back. Can the API_URL be set in linux or only in package.json?

Comment: You can set it linux also. usually confidential secrets are best to be present in the OS or set dynamically during the build process..

Answer (score 1):

If the REST server and the API share a common server, you could just omit the IP address entirely, so instead of

```
axios.get('http://123.4.567.89/user?ID=12345')
```

you can just

```
axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
```

Other than that, using DNS is usually a better way:

```
axios.get('http://my.domain/user?ID=12345')
```

Comment: It is being served from a local network machine and being viewed on the local network. So that rules out DNS. I will still give the no url option a try.

Comment: '/user?ID=12345' simply worked for me.  This should be marked the answer.